# Run a specific assignment process multiple times in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have been trying to run a process where I take a specific product and run a method where I associated 74 additional  unassociated tags to it:

```
Product.where(id:194617) do |product|
  product.74.times do
    tag = Tag.unassociated.last
    tag.location = Warehouse.primary
    tag.trackable = product
    tag.save!
  end
end

 irb):43: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('
  product.74.times do
```

Flipping the nest returns the number of times in the loop, but does not produce results (attaching the unassociated tags to the Product):

```
 74.times do
  Product.where(id:194617) do |product|
    rfid_tag = RFIDTag.unassociated.last
    rfid_tag.location = Warehouse.primary
    rfid_tag.trackable = product
    rfid_tag.save!
  end
end
```

Products `have_many` tags, and tags `have_one` product.

The method in place works find for associating single tags to a group of products. How can I built the `times` loop into the system?

It would actually be ideal if I could run a range `(Product.where(id >= 194617 AND id <= 194638)`), but I need to solve the inner loop first.

Method derived from:

```
Product.all.each do |product|
    tag = Tag.unassociated.last
    tag.location = Warehouse.primary
    tag.trackable = product
    tag.save! 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved both parts of this by calling the ids I needed as a range:

```
Product.where(id:194617..194638).each do |product|
  74.times do
    tag = Tag.unassociated.last
    tag.location = Warehouse.primary
    tag.trackable = product
    tag.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) for such a use-case:

```
Product.where(id:194617).first.tap do |product|
  74.times do
    tag = Tag.unassociated.last
    tag.location = Warehouse.primary
    tag.trackable = product
    tag.save!
  end
end
```

`tap` yields `self` (in this case the specific product) to the block and returns `self` afterward.

Comment: Strange. I ran this, then tried again line by line and got `irb(main):016:0>     tag.trackable = Product.where(id:194617)
NoMethodError: undefined method `primary_key' for Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class``

Comment: @Boucherie: because spickermann meant `Product.where(id:194617).first.tap`

Comment: Exactly, I fixed my answer.